# find possible combinations where average price on display is improved by 50 cents

Tags: excel, vba

This is a Mix Management exercise. By writing a macro, find out all possible combinations where change in revenue is maintained and average price on display is improved by 50 cents. All the possible combinations should be placed in an appropriate format in a new sheet within this file.

You can only change the quantity for the four on display pack types. Keep in mind that on-display pack types should not exceed 15 packs.

```
Mini Pack   Small Pack  Large Pack  Ultra Large Pack    
Total
On Display: 3.75000025  3.75000025  3.75000025  3.75000025  15.000001
Revenue:     $400    $275    $176    $360   


RESULTS Large Pack  Selected    Change      
Revenue  $10,640.00      $7,314.85  (31%)       
Price    $5.32   $6.04  14%     
         $0.72      0   




Mini Pack   Small Pack  Large Pack  Ultra Large Pack    
 $5.32   $10.40      $5.67   $3.69  

0    $-      $-      $-      $-     
1    $133    $150    $175    $120   
2    $267    $225    $176    $240   
3    $400    $275    $176    $360   
4    $533    $313    $176    $480   
5    $667    $343    $177    $600   
6    $800    $368    $177    $720   
7    $933    $389    $177    $840   
8    $1,067      $408    $177    $960   
9    $1,200      $424    $177    $1,080     
10   $1,333      $439    $178    $1,200     
11   $1,467      $453    $178    $1,320     
12   $1,600      $465    $178    $1,440     
13   $1,733      $477    $178    $1,560     
14   $1,867      $488    $178    $1,680     
15   $2,000      $498    $178    $1,800     
15   $2,000          $1,000      $1,800
```

I tried recording macro while using solver and then ran the loop but solver itself is unable to give proper result. Apart from this I also tried, running combinations for 4 columns using VBA and then adding constraints as mentioned but getting error message 'Overflow error' and 'Application defined type error'.Please help me out

```
Sub combinations()
Dim c1() As Variant
    Dim c2() As Variant
    Dim c3() As Variant
    Dim c4() As Variant
    'Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim out() As Variant
    Dim j As Long, k As Long, l As Long, m As Long, n As Long

    'Set Sheet5 = ActiveSheet
    Dim col1 As Range
    Dim col2 As Range
    Dim col3 As Range
    Dim col4 As Range
    Dim out1 As Range


    'Set col1 = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    'Set col2 = Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown))
    'Set col3 = Range("C1", Range("C1").End(xlDown))
    'Set col4 = Range("D1", Range("D1").End(xlDown))
    Set col1 = Range("A1:A204")
    Set col2 = Range("B1:B204")
    Set col3 = Range("C1:C204")
    Set col4 = Range("D1:D204")

    c1 = col1
    c2 = col2
    c3 = col3
    c4 = col4

    'Set ws = Sheets.Add
    'Sheets.Add.Name = output
    Set out1 = Range("J2", Range("N2").Offset(UBound(c1) * UBound(c2) * UBound(c3) * UBound(c4)))
    out = out1

    j = 1
    k = 1
    l = 1
    m = 1
    n = 1

    If Sheets("updated").Range("D9").Value + Sheets("updated").Range("E9").Value + Sheets("updated").Range("F9").Value + Sheets("updated").Range("G9").Value = 15 Then
       If Sheets("updated").Range("E14").Value = Sheets("updated").Range("D14").Value Then
    Do While j <= UBound(c1)
        Do While k <= UBound(c2)
            Do While l <= UBound(c3)
                Do While m <= UBound(c4)
                    out(n, 1) = c1(j, 1)
                    out(n, 2) = c2(k, 1)
                    out(n, 3) = c3(l, 1)
                    out(n, 4) = c4(m, 1)
                    n = n + 1
                    m = m + 1
                Loop
                m = 1
                l = l + 1
            Loop
            l = 1
            k = k + 1
        Loop
        k = 1
        j = j + 1
    Loop


    out1.Value = out
    End If
End If
End Sub

'End Sub
```

and one more small code I tried but nothing works

```
Sub SolverMacro()
'
' mymacro Macro
'

'
Dim i As Integer

 For i = 1 To 24
 'ResetSolver
 SolverReset

    SolverOk SetCell:="$E$14", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:="10640", ByChange:= _
        "$D$9:$G$9"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$H$9", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="15"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$E$14", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:="$D$14", ByChange:= _
        Sheets("updated").Range("$D$9:$G$9").Offset(i, 0).Address
    SolverSolve (True)

    SolverSolve userFinish:=True
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
    If Sheets("updated").Range("$E$14").Value = 10640 Then

    Sheets("updated").Range("$D$9:$G$9").Offset(i, 0).Value = Sheets("output").Range("$A$2:$D$2").Value



    End If
    Next i
    MsgBox ("Processing done")

End Sub
```

Expected output should be :

Total must be 15 and

```
RESULTS Large Pack  Selected    Change  
Revenue  $10,640.00 $10,640     (0%)    This should be 0%
Price    $5.32      $5.82        9% 
                    $0.50   This should be improved by 50 cents
```